# Delete the not related objects in a django model (manytomanyfield)

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a model that is used in other models as related. (The example is just to give an idea of the model)

```
class A(Models.model):
     locations = models.manytomanyfield(Location)

class B(Models.model):
      location = models.foreignkeyfield(Location)

class Location(Models.model):
      foo = models.charfield(...)
```

Now I want delete all the location instance that are not related to A and B. For the foreignkeyfield in the class B is easy using the filter(), but for the manytomany field in the class A, I wonder if there is a way to query the join map directly.

If I'm right the join map should be **A.locations.through**, how I can query the location in that table using the Django ORM? Maybe there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

We take actual locations from models A and B, then make set from ids, then remove all in Location model, that not used.

```
set_a = set(A.objects.all().values_list('locations', flat=True)
set_b = set(B.objects.all().values_list('locations', flat=True)
locations = set_a | set_b
locations.discard(None)
Location.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=locations)).delete()
```